# User not found in SigninRedirectCallback Oidc-Client

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

We have been using Oidc-Client js for SPA application.Below are the clarifications.

1. We were able to implement signinRedirect but not sure how to implement and handle signinRedirectCallback method to get user and token responses. Hence kindly provide the sample to use the same.
2. Regarding silent renew token, once it's generated silently then when it expires.

Answer (score 0):

I have some resources on this and a sample that helps with testing of expiry events:

- [Renewal Code from Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth)
- When the session expires, eg if the user leaves the browser running overnight, you check for a login_required error code

Blog Posts:

- [SPA Token Renewal](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/)
- [Code Sample Overview](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/13/improved-spa-code-sample-overview/)

Comment: Thanks Gary... I will go through and let you know if still have doubt....